# Weird behavior on form data signature with a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, rsa, haml, signature

## Case study

I have 2 apps (`Rails` => the sender and `Laravel` => the receiver) in which I sign data using a private and public key in order to ensure the accuracy of information between request. The data are sent from one app to another using GET parameters :

```
domain.com/callback?order_id=12&time=2015-10-01T22:38:20Z&signature=VX2WxlTaGK5N12GhZ5oqXU5h3wW/I70MYZhLbAYNQ79pFquuhdOerwBwqaq2BRuGyhKoY6VEHJkNnFjLAJkQD6Q5z4Vmk...
```

## Problem

I'm experiencing an odd behavior between the **staging** server and the **local** one regarding the signature of those datas.

When testing on staging, the generate link (GET) looks like (source code from chrome) :

[image: Link generation]

*And on the local server, it's the exact same formatted html (except the data that change of course). By the way, I'm using HAML*

The callback URL is generated from a decorator :

```
def url_to_store
  params    = url_params.to_a.map { |a| a.join('=') }.join('&')
  signature = Shield::Crypto.new(params).signature
  "#{object.referer}?#{params}&signature=#{signature}"
end

def url_params
  {
    order_id:       object.id,
    transaction_id: object.transaction_id,
    user_id:        object.user_id,
    status:         object.status,
    time:           Time.now.utc.iso8601,
    reference:      object.success? ? object.reference : ''
  }
end
```

When clicking on the link from the staging, I get redirected to the other app which actually validate the signature. Every thing works.

However, the same thing does not apply to the locale server (my machine). When clicking on the link, the signature contains spaces (`%20`) :

```
signature=wP5EmeIGzXynwJc+BDV+jGVzyYhZOJuu7PzCXgnP2qbBfdqrAceEjxgh1EH2%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tvR66o3IA
```

Which of course make the other app reject the request as the signature is invalid. **That's my issue**. The exact same app. The exact same code base and version (a.k.a commit sha). Different behavior.

I don't know how to reproduce it. I was hoping some of you guys already experienced similar cases and could give me a hint.

Ideas?

NOTE: I'm using the exact same callback url (local PHP app) to test both the staging and the local server. I don't think the problem comes from the PHP app. Something related to a Rails debug stuff maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from `Haml` and it's `ugly` mode. In `development`, it is set to `false` by default which causes the HTML code to be pad and somehow was messing with the signature.

The related github issues has been found here https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/636 and here https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/828

So to fix it, I created an initializer to enable it as default :

**config/initializers/haml.rb**

```
require 'haml/template'
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true
```